# Gltf export with animation not working

Tags: animation, export, gltf

I'm trying to export a .gltf with animation, but it doesn't work. I turned on "animation" in the export window, but it doesn't export animation. if I then import the .gltf back into blender, the object is exactly the same only without animation ...

(I work with the blender version: 2.81.16)[image]

Answer (score -2):

I have same problem at 2.81 and automatically resolved at 2.83.
For migration to 2.83 attention to project import routine. It make some change at object and some minor options.

Comment: Incomprehensible answer.

Comment: yes,but is not wrong information and just a personal experience sharing